# Integration SpringSecurity, SpringData with SpEL support

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I try realize a integration of SpringSecurity and SpringData but I receive error When I starting the application, my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I created the class:

```
public class SecurityEvaluationContextExtension extends EvaluationContextExtensionSupport {

      @Override
      public String getExtensionId() {
        return "security";
      }

      @Override
      public SecurityExpressionRoot getRootObject() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return new SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication) {};
      }
}
```

And I created the configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
     }
```

When I start the application I receive teh error above:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authentication object cannot be null
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot.      <init>(SecurityExpressionRoot.java:61)
at br.com.wts.mobione.conf.security.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension$1. <init>(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:18)
at br.com.wts.mobione.conf.security.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.getRootObject(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:18)
at br.com.wts.mobione.conf.security.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.getRootObject(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:1)
```

I followed this tutorial:

[enter link description here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions)

Thank you.